# Is there a recent or known issue with the #flurry Dashboard?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

Our #flurry App Activity dashboard appears bugged. It only queries data from the first of every month, independent of the date range requested. Is this a known issue or recent bug? Everything was working fine just five days ago, and we haven't changed anything on the code side. Image of the current dashboard below:

[Bugged App Activity Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhK2R.png)

Comment: if I were you, I would, check with flurry support boards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking at monthly data, Flurry pulls the whole month for any dates in your date range. Here it is showing all of August and September to date. If you want only September, you can change your dates to start September 1st. (Note that there is a time zone issue that can impact date selection, so you may need to change the first date to September 2nd in the date selector.) Alternatively, you could change your time grain to weekly or daily. Feel free to contact support@flurry.com if you'd like more assistance.

Comment: Solved.Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.